# Copy from MobileMe to iPhoto

Tags: iphoto, mobileme

I published an album to MobileMe, and someone else has uploaded photos to the gallery.  In iPhoto now I can see the uploaded photos, but I'd like to add them to my regular library.  What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select the MobileMe gallery in iPhoto, select the photos you want to copy, and drag them over to the main "Photos" album up at the top of your album list.  That will add the photos to the main library, so they will show up in your photo list, event list, etc.